# Can anyone help me with React Installation? I am getting this weird error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

After struggling for days, searching StackOverflow, and reading tutorials, I am stuck with react installation. I am sharing step by step of what I did.

Node version is 14.15.3.

Run `npx create-react-app blog` and this is the result:

```
`Creating a new React app in C:\My Garbage\Html & CSS\React.js\blog.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...




> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\My Garbage\Html & CSS\React.js\blog\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.8.1 postinstall C:\My Garbage\Html & CSS\React.js\blog\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.8.1 postinstall C:\My Garbage\Html & CSS\React.js\blog\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\My Garbage\Html & CSS\React.js\blog\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

+ react@17.0.1
+ react-scripts@4.0.1
+ cra-template@1.1.1
+ react-dom@17.0.1
added 1903 packages from 721 contributors and audited 1907 packages in 116.704s

124 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.2.1 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.2.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @testing-library/jest-dom@5.11.6
+ web-vitals@0.2.4
+ @testing-library/user-event@12.6.0
+ @testing-library/react@11.2.2
added 29 packages from 77 contributors and audited 1936 packages in 10.711s

124 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.2.1 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.2.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

removed 1 package and audited 1935 packages in 6.56s

124 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


Created git commit.

Success! Created blog at C:\My Garbage\Html & CSS\React.js\blog
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd blog
  npm start

Happy hacking!`
```

`cd blog`

Now while running `npm start` i am getting this error:

````
$ npm start

> blog@0.1.0 start C:\My Garbage\Html & CSS\React.js\blog
> react-scripts start

'CSS\React.js\blog\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\My Garbage\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! blog@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the blog@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JYOTIRMOY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-29T10_59_15_177Z-debug.log```

    Hoping for your valuable help :)
````

Comment: Try to run again the `npm install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to use more 'normal' paths for your projects.
Computers dislike spaces, but have learned to deal with them.
But the & sign in your path breaks the command. Bash interprets it as
`blog@0.1.0 start C:\My Garbage\Html` & `CSS\React.js\blog`, which is why it tells you that it couldn't find 'CSS\React.js\blog\node_modules...'

The easiest way to fix it is renaming your folder to something without &

Comment: This did fix the bug. Thank you Lukas!